# How to make CarPlay and Google maps coexist peacefully

Tags: iphone, car-integration

The 2018 Subaru I bought has a "Starlink" media center that supports CarPlay. I have an iPhone 7, tethered to the player by USB. For various reasons I strongly prefer Google Maps to Apple Maps. However, if I'm playing anything in the foreground (radio, podcast) and Google Maps interrupts it with spoken instructions, the media doesn't resume playing afterward.

The problem doesn't happen when using Apple Maps.

There's very little documentation about how CarPlay, apps, and the media center co-operate. I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me as to how to make CarPlay work in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From information I received on Subaru's forum: it apparently is not possible to use Google Maps on CarPlay in the Starlink head unit of the 2018 Subaru Crosstrek Premium, and have it relinquish the audio channel to whatever was using it before it was interrupted for a spoken driving instruction. Only Apple Maps can do that - at least, currently; it's unknown whether this functionality could be added to Google Maps.

Here is a link to the discussion: http://www.subaruxvforum.com/forum/interior-audio/162970-using-google-maps-carplay.html

Answer (score 5):

This is likely an issue with your Starlink media center. Try looking through the settings on it for an autoplay on connect or something similar. In my car's media station, a bluetooth connection will pause and auto-play when using Google Maps, but does not always perform the same when using the USB connection.

Comment: Also check the settings for a resume playback after notification or phone call.

Comment: @christian - with Bluetooth but no USB, I can only use the phone. None of the iPhone apps (like Google Maps) will play through the Starlink unless USB is also connected. Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: @Melvin - I can’t find any such setting in the four sets of Starlink setting groups (general, sound, phone, vehicle). Sound is all about volumes; Phone simply lists my phone; Vehicle does not affect the media player at all; General only contains a switch to auto play USB device.

Comment: @Chap make sure that auto-play is active.

Comment: @Christian if you're referring to Settings>General> Autoplay when USB device is connected, it is active.

Someone on a Subaru forum, with a vehicle identical to mine, states that it's **not** possible to do what I'm asking. Are you saying that you **are** able to hear Google Maps' spoken directions on your car speakers with only a BT connection between your iPhone and the CarPlay-enabled media center?

Comment: My media center is not CarPlay enabled, but I am able to hear Google Maps's spoken directions and have my media resume afterwards with just a bluetooth connection. It may be that the Subaru forum is correct and this operation is not possible with the Starlink media center.